# Exterior power of symmetric product of GL(2,R) tensor representations

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-decomposition

A paper I am reading uses an identification of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ representations:

\begin{align}
\Lambda^2(\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2) = (\text{Sym}^4\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes  \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 ) \oplus (\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2)
\end{align}

which wasn't obvious to me. I've tried solving this the following way: First write

\begin{align}
\otimes^2 (\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2) = \Lambda^2(\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2) \oplus \text{Sym}^2(\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2)
\end{align}

Now I -think- there is an isomorphism of representations

\begin{align}
\phi:\otimes^2 (\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2) \cong \text{Sym}^6\mathbb{R}^2 \oplus(\text{Sym}^4\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 ) \oplus (\text{Sym}^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2) \oplus  (\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2) 
\end{align}
where all the terms in the decomposition are irreducible representations.
Then given this isomorphism, the image of the 6-dimensional $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ invariant subspace $\Lambda^2(\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2))$ must be the invariant subspace $ (\text{Sym}^4\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes  \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 ) \oplus (\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^2)$ by a count on dimensions.

My problem is I can't find the isomorphism $\phi$. Given a tensor $T \in \otimes^2 (\text{Sym}^3\mathbb{R}^2)$ with components $T^{abcdef}$ with $T^{(abc)(def)} = T^{abcdef}$. I have tried the obvious map, namely: Total symmetrisation in the first component of the map $\phi$, symmetrisation $(abde)$ and antisymmetrisation $[cf]$ in the second component, symmetrisation $(ad)$ and antisymmetrisation $[be]$ $[cf]$ in the third component. Then in the last component $[ad]$ $[be]$ $[cf]$. But I can't see why this gives an isomorphism, even when I try to enforce the required symmetries on $T$ such that $T$ is in the kernel of the map I just described.

Comment: The decomposition looks correct, but I'm unclear as to what you want the map $\phi$ to look like. Do you want to be able to find projectors onto each component on the right, or are you realising the right hand side as some formal direct sum?

Comment: Yes, finding projectors onto the components on the right is my aim.